# Calculate division according to a more granular level in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create a new metric in Tableau that is division of other 2 metrics:

```
new metric = metric A / metric B
```

This works, but when I add this metric as sum(new metric) in my view grouped by a more aggregated field than the original field (e.g. the dataset is in city granularity, but I want to see it by state), the metric is summed and not recalculated.
I'm used to Excel pivot table, which recalculates the calculated field according to granularity, how can I get a similar behavior in Tableau?

Comment: This way the problem is not very clear, could you share a sample worksheet? And meanwhile you may try to change your metric's formula as:` SUM(metric A) / SUM(metric B)` and see whether anything changes.

Comment: It sounds as though you need to use Level of Detail expressions, see more detail here: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new metric = SUM(metric A) / SUM(metric B)`

Sounds like you're trying to make a weighted average, which would be the calculation above.

Think about what is happening in your calculated field. For each city you calculated A/B, then when you use the calculation at the state level, you are summing each of those values.

In the example above, when used at the state level, you are summing A and dividing by sum B.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Table calculations for this purpose,

From your explanation looks like City is last level of granularity that is the reason division of 2 metrics is working but when you move to the higher level of granularity you can use LoD or Move to windows calcualtin where you need to give the starting and ending of the partition and then select the partition where you need to calculate.

LoD

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html

Table Calculations

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html